# Modifying the Core Data Model Requires New Version Every Time?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I've been searching around and let me get this straight, every time I change the attributes of my entities, I need to create an entirely new version of my model? I understand that the SQLite database is now out of sync with my data model, but can't I just delete the sql files and re-run my simulator? This is what I've been doing, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, any changes to the core data model must be made in a new core data model version. You can avoid having to do this for development builds by resetting content and settings in the simulator, or deleting the old app version on a device before installing. For store builds though, you must correctly manage your model versions so that user's will have their persistent store properly migrated to a new store with the new model. Versioning is required so that lightweight migrations can be performed, without you having to write custom migration code. If you don't want to version your model, you are bound to writing code to properly migrate your entities. This can be a lot of work and difficult to maintain, you'd rather use lightweight migration and versioning.

Comment: Thanks man. So for resting content and settings in simulator, I would delete the app icon? And "store builds" you mean apps that are published and downloaded on devices?

Comment: That's correct, deleting the app from the simulator or device will remove any files that exist for the app so the next time your app runs it will create a new database file using your modified model.  The app will be unable to open the existing file if you have made changes to the model that was used to create the file.

Comment: Store builds means apps available on App Store and where the database contains user data that needs to be retained.  If you release a new version with a modified core data model then unless you use a versioned model you will be unable to use automatic lightweight migration.