# Core data save model not working iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, console, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I have created a core data model and when trying to save records I get the following console message: `Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x8b3bc50 {metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "F49C0E04-9778-46EC-A9C7-9A045CD915D8";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 479;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "F49C0E04-9778-46EC-A9C7-9A045CD915D8";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}`

I am not sure where to start to debug it please can someone tell me where the problem could be as I am new to core data.

Comment: Did you make a change to the model? Any time you change the model, you need to delete the app from the Simulator or the iphone and re-run it

Comment: The error is giving you this explanation: `The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`

Comment: check out my answer here, you need to version your Core Data Model for every set of changes you make to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364660/modifying-the-core-data-model-requires-new-version-every-time/20364770#20364770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your app from the simulator or device, clean the project and run it again.

Update:
Do this only for development stages and be sure to understand the model versioning like Patrick Goley stated below.

Comment: this is an incomplete answer. OP doesn't understand model versioning, which can create big problems if he ships a bad model version because you convinced him it's only a problem with the simulator

Comment: @PatrickGoley that cannot be inferred either that he might ship an app that way. being that he is saying he created a core data model and its not working likely means its the 1st go around. He likely created the datamodel used it then changed something.

Comment: But i do agree its an incomplete answer and should be better detailed.